# pdf security when submitting via button fdf data

Tags: security, pdf, https, fdf

I can send data via a button in a pdf file just fine and receive it. My question is if im sending to a https site is the data encrypted? So if someone where to send there SSN would it be encrypted and safe or is there a better way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are submitting via https, the transmission is by definition encrypted.

That said, there are several additional requirements that arise when transmitting information such as SSNs, and you should probably look into these.

Comment: thanks i wasn't sure since its not via a website but a pdf document